# How prevent double entry in tab after refresh by the client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I build a booking form for my festival's public. But i have lot's of double entry in my array. Cause by refreash.

How i can on Ruby on Rails clean the form after submit ? Or prevent this problem by an other way ?

MAJ: I post here my view, my controller and my model

```
<%= simple_form_for @booking do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <%= f.input :first_name, label: 'Prénom' %>
    <%= f.input :last_name, label: 'Nom'  %>
    <%= f.input :email, label: 'Email'  %>
    <%= f.input :phone, as: :integer, label: 'Téléphone'  %>

    <%= f.input :member, as: :integer, label: false, input_html: {id: 'quantite_1', value: 0, min: "0", onchange: 'prix()'} %>
    <%= f.input :member_not, as: :integer, label: false, input_html: {id: 'quantite_2', value: 0, min: "0", onchange: 'prix()'} %>

    <%= f.button :submit, 'Réserver', class: 'uk-button red-full button' %>
<%end%>
```

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_booking, only: [:show]

  def index
    @booking = Booking.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def show
  end

  def create
    @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)

    if @booking.save
      BookingMailer.confirmation_booking(@booking).deliver_now
      BookingMailer.alert_booking(@booking).deliver_now
      redirect_to festivals_path
    else
      render :index, notice: ''
    end
  end

  private

  def set_booking
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
  end

  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name, :phone, :member, :member_not, :young, :so_young, :exonere, :representation_id)
  end
end
```

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :representation

  validate :test

  validates :last_name, presence: true
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true

  private

  def test
    if member_not + member <= 0
      errors.add(:member, "Il vous faut au moins 1 place")
    end
  end
end
```

Sometimes I receive two similar booking

Comment: Can you please give some more information like code snippets?

Comment: Thx for your replie : i update my post

Comment: I think it is still not clear what your question is. The simple_form for booking leads to the bookings controller, but you only showed the Admin::ReservationsController. ALso what do you mean by ` clean the form after submit`?

Comment: I try to be more clear :) When a user submit a booking, in my back office, It's possible I have 2 similar entry. That's arrive when I come back after submit : the form is submit again. So i look for a way to prevent this disadvantage and I think clean the cache of the form is maybe one solution. What do you think ? It's more clear ? I hope ;)

Comment: You should add validations to the booking, so a user cannot book twice (for example uniqueness on the user_id for bookings).
But since I can't see the bookngs controller I don't know why you get the same bookings twice. It normally doesn't happen

Comment: My bad... ReservationController is the BookingController it's an error of me when i create the booking method.

Comment: But there is no create method. If you submit the simple_form which is stated above. It is going by defintion to a booking controller to a create method or, if it's an edit form to an update method. It's hard to help you when from the code above you can't see them problem

Comment: I'm so sorry ! I put the booking controller use for administrator and not for visitor... I change it in my post. Sorry again. I hope you have a better view now

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since in there is no code in your controller or view which could cause the double entries, the easiest way would be to put a validation on the booking model.
So in the booking model I would add:

```
validates :email, uniqueness: true
```

The downside is, that a user can only book tickets with this email address once. But if you can live with that, it'll should be fine.